# How can security models be relevant to the current environment?

Tags: access-control, integrity

I am trying to understand the Clark-Wilson and Brewer Nash Security Models.

After deep research, I couldn't find any solution or idea to find

out the relevance of these models in the current environment.

Can someone explain it? It could be helpful if the explanation came with examples or scenarios.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't think they are relevant?  When I look at just the wikipedia article for Clark-Wilson, and the beginnings of the paper by Brewer Nash on their model, I see relevance everywhere.  You may be having trouble interpreting them, in which case it would help to see your interpretation.

Comment: My question is how these models are relevant to current environment. I am stuck without ideas about it. I am still learning them. Sorry if I am not clear.

Comment: From reading wikipedia, Clark-Wilson is relevant whenever you want to limit access to something using a policy (such as only people running a cachier's station can void a sale).  Brewer Nash is relevant whenever there is a legal statute requiring you to make sure no one person has two pieces of information (such as any reverse engineering scenario).  Because there are people who want policy-based security, and because we still reverse engineer code under US laws, both are relevant to the current environment.